# Print response from doOnError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to implement this code with Spring web flux:
Can you guide me how I can call the two methods `parseRawSuccessResponse` and `parseRawFailedResponse` based on the client response codes because I have different return values? Also how this code can be implemented without using block()?

I tried this:

```
Mono<AuthorizeRequest> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
        return client.post().uri(checkTrailingSlash(gatewayUrl) + token)
                .body(transactionMono, AuthorizeRequest.class)
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {

                        return Mono.error(RuntimeException::new);
                    }
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(AuthorizeResponse.class);
                });
```

// parse response:

```
result.map(fooBar -> {
                    return parseRawSuccessResponse(fooBar);
                }).doOnError(throwable -> {                                 
//                  return parseRawFailedResponse(throwable);
                }).block();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the available disjunction type implementations available for java.

```
val result: Mono<Either<ClientError, AuthorizeResponse>> = 
    client.post().uri(checkTrailingSlash(gatewayUrl) + token)
        .body(transactionMono, AuthorizeRequest.class)
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> {
            if (clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                return response.bodyToMono(AuthorizeResponse.class).map(Either::right);
            } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                return response.bodyToMono(ClientError.class).map(Either::left);
            } else {
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Unexpected response type"));
            }
        });
```

You can implement disjunction type yourself of just use existing implementations. One of the popular options would be: [vavr.io](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/1.0.0-alpha-3/io/vavr/control/Either.html)

Answering the second part of your question, use `Mono.subscribe()`. It's not idiomatic to escape reactive context with `.block()` you just need to build your computation chain in terms of Monos and Fluxes and then do a single subscribe at the end.